# How can I transfer an image captured by gstreamer to another machine without writing a file?

Tags: linux, gstreamer

I am capturing an image using `gstreamer`:

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src ! ffmpegcolorspace ! pngenc ! filesink location=$date.png
```

I am then `scp`ing the file to a remote server:

```
scp $date.png remote:pics
```

What I would like to do is skip the file on the local filesystem step.  Can I do something like

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src ! ffmpegcolorspace ! pngenc | ssh remote "cat > pics/$date.png"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reading that

```
cat file | ssh uid@remotehost 'cat > /full/path/file'
```

should do what you need (replace `cat file` with your plumbing), but I am not sure how much of a hack is it (how will it perform on decently sized streams.

Alternative is to somehow mount the remote point - sshfs, cifs, nfs and then no magic is necessary.

Comment: The trick is getting the file contents to come out on `stdout` (thay is what I don't know, this is more of a gstreamer question than a how does `ssh` work question).  The `sshfs` idea has merit though, that should be easy enough to setup